# Get next record WHERE

Tags: php, sql

I have a page on my site

```
site.com/leads/id=1
```

It loads data with the following query

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$lead = $this->db->get_where("leads", ["leadid" => $id]);
$lead = $lead->row();
```

I have a column in my leads table called `USERID`.
Lets imagine the current page they are on the `USERID` is set to 9.

How can I get the next and the previous ID from the database WHERE username is 9?

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Subtract 1 and add 1from $id, then re-run query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the previous and next record using a single query in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084390/how-to-find-the-previous-and-next-record-using-a-single-query-in-mysql)

Comment: It's worth noting that "next" and "previous" depend entirely on how you sort the data.  Do you always sort ascending by `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do it in separate queries, the next will be

```
$this->db->get_where("leads", ["leadid" > $id, "username" => 9]);
```

and the previous will be

```
$this->db->get_where("leads", ["leadid" < $id, "username" => 9]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `$lead` variable so with the first row of the data source, so that you cannot load the next row.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$lead = $this->db->get_where("leads", ["leadid" => $id]);
$firstRow = $lead->row();
$secondRow = $lead->row();
$thirdRow = $lead->row();
```